# How make a query with date format parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in Postgresql. I need to count the total records by month and year, for example:

Total: 100 records

Year 2018, month 01: 50
Year 2018, month 02: 50

With the total I have no problem:

```
select count(id) from users;
```

but how can I make the query for the dates indicated?

The date format is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`

Comment: `date` or `timestamp` columns do not have "a format"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't specify the data type of your date column, i.e. whether the date is a string in the format you provided or an actual timestamp.

In case of the date formatted as string, you should be able to group the counted records by a substring of the date like this:

```
select count(id), 
       substr(date, 1, 7) as year_mon 
from users 
group by substr(date, 1, 7);
```

For a genuine timestamp PostgreSQL provides corresponding truncation methods:

```
select count(id), 
       date_trunc('month', date) as year_mon 
from users 
group by date_trunc('month', date);
```